problem on double integral
Let $G:[0,1] \times[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined as
$$
G(t, x)=\begin{cases}
t(1-x), & \text { if }  t \leq x \leq 1 \\
x(1-t), & \text { if }  x \leq t \leq 1 
\end{cases}.
$$
For a continuous function $f$ on $[0,1]$, define
$$
I[f]=\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} G(t, x) f(t) f(x) dt\,dx
$$
Now i want to prove  $I[f]>0$ if $f$ is not identically zero. I get by symmetry
$$
I[f]=2\int_{0}^{1} \int_{x}^{1} x(1-t) f(t) f(x) dt\,dx
$$
by reducing it i get this leaves me no where. now i dont know how i can proceed , i have thought about green functions still no steps to go ahead.

I do not have a complete proof in mind, but notice that $f(t)f(x)$ is nonnegative in a neighborhood of the diagonal (and positive on a set of positive measure by continuity if $f$ is not identically $0$). Also note that the integral of $G(x,t)$ over $[0,1/2]\times [0,1/2]$ (and, symmetrically, $[1/2,1]\times [1/2,1]$) is three times the integral over $[0,1/2]\times [1/2,1]$ (and $[1/2,1]\times [0,1/2]$). Perhaps then approximate $f$ by a simple function and just write it down?

i still dont get it ,why the integral is   positive  after all breaking  $G(x,t)$ gave me nothing

All you used is the symmetry of the problem. As I indicated, you need to know that $G$ is largest along the diagonal and decays as you move to the edges of the square. So you want to break the problem down into a neighborhood of the diagonal and the region "far away."

Is $f$ positive?

No bro just continuous

Using the identity
$$
G(x,t)=\frac{2}{\pi^2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\,\sin(n\pi x)\sin(n\pi t), \tag{1}
$$
one can rewrite the integral as
$$
I[f]=\frac{2}{\pi^2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{f_n^2}{n^2}, \tag{2}
$$
where
$$
f_n=\int_0^1f(s)\sin(n\pi s)\,ds. \tag{3}
$$
If $f$ is continuous in $[0,1]$ and not identically zero, $\exists n\in\mathbb{N}_{>0}$ such that $f_n\neq 0$, hence $I[f]>0$.

Solution (a)
Any kernel of the form
$$G(x,t)=\langle v_x,v_t\rangle_{\mathcal{H}},\quad 0\le x,t\le 1$$ is positive semidefinite, where $[0,1]\ni x\mapsto v_x\in \mathcal{H}$ is a continuous mapping.
Indeed $$\int\limits_0^1\int\limits_0^1G(x,t)f(t)f(x)\,dx\,dt=\int\limits_0^1\int\limits_0^1\langle v_t,v_x\rangle_{\mathcal{H}}f(t)f(x)\,dx\,dt\\ =\left \langle \int\limits_0^1f(t)v_t\,dt, \int\limits_0^1f(x)v_x\,dx\right \rangle_{\mathcal{H}}\ge 0$$
Observe that $G(x,t)=\min\{x,t\}-xt.$ Let $\mathcal{H}=L^2(0,1)$ and
$v_t(y)={\bf 1}_{[0,t]}(y)-t.$ Then $$\langle v_x,v_t\rangle_{L^2(0,1)} = \min\{x,t\}-xt=G(x,t)
$$
Thus $G(x,t)$ is positive semidefinite. Next
assume the quadratic form vanishes for some $f.$ Then for any $0\le y\le 1$ we have
$$0=\int\limits_0^1f(t)v_t(y)\,dt=\int\limits_y^1f(t)\,dt -\int\limits_0^1tf(t)\,dt$$
Thus the function $y\mapsto \int\limits_y^1f(t)\,dt$ is constant, which implies $f=0.$ Therefore the quadratic form is  positive definite.
Solution (b)
Consider the operator
$$(Tf)(x)=\int\limits_0^1G(x,t)f(t)\,dt$$ Due to the symmetry $G(x,t)=G(t,x)$ the operator is selfadjoint. Moreover as $G\in L^2([0,1]\times [0,1])$ the operator $T$ is Hilbert-Schmidt. In particular $T$ is compact. We need to show that
$$I(f)=\langle Tf,f\rangle_{L^2(0,1)}>0,\quad f\neq 0$$  Due to the compactness and selfadjointness it suffices to show that all the eigenvalues of $T$ are positive.
Assume $f$ is an eigenfunction of $T.$ Then
$$(Tf)(x)=\int\limits_0^xtf(t)\,dt +x\int\limits_x^1f(t)\,dt -x\int\limits_0^1tf(t)\,dt =\lambda f(x)$$ Thus $f$ is continuous as LHS is continuous. By iterating we get that $f$ is twice differentiable.
Plugging in $x=0$ and $x=1$ gives $f(0)=f(1)=0.$ Applying the second derivative implies
$$\lambda f''=- f,\quad f(0)=f(1)=0$$ For $\lambda<0$ the solutions are
$f(x)=ae^{(-\lambda)^{-1/2} \,x}+be^{-(-\lambda)^{-1/2}\,x}$ and the boundary conditions are not satisfied for any choice of $a$ and $b,$ except $a=b=0.$ For $\lambda=0$ we get $f(x)=0.$  Therefore $\lambda>0$ which completes the proof.
For $\lambda>0$ the solutions are
$$a\cos(\lambda^{-1/2}x)+b\sin(\lambda^{-1/2}x)$$ The boundary conditions are satisfied only when $a=0$ and $\lambda=(\pi n)^{-2}.$ Hence the eigenfunctions of $T$ are $\sin(\pi nx).$

Consider the symmetric matrix $A_n=(\min(i,j)-\frac{ij}{n})$ of order $n$ which is positive definite since $$x^TA_nx=(1-\frac{1}{n})(x_1+\cdots+x_n)^2+\sum_{k=2}^n(x_k+\cdots+x_n)^2.$$ We approximate $I(f)$ by
$I_n=\frac{1}{n}f^T_nA_nf_n$ where $f_n(k)=f(k/n)$. Clearly $I_n\to I(f)\geq 0.$

The kernel has the form
$$G(x,y)= \min(x,y) - x y$$.
The kernel is positive and symmetric, so the integral is metric scalar product.  Evaluated for identical functions $f(x), f(y)$ it suffices to show that the symmetrized products of powers are positive
$$\int _0^1\int _0^1(\min (u,v)-u v) \left(u^{m-2} v^{n-2}+v^{m-2} u^{n-2}\right)dvdu=\frac{2}{m n (m+n-1)}$$

Sorry for being pain in ... Every quadratic nonnegative kernel is nonnegative on nonnegative functions. But it does not mean the kernel is positive semidefinite.

Sure, my interest was to identify the dsitributional form of the kernel and its action on these special form of  pairs $\left< f(x)1(y) . 1(x)f(y)\right>$ in the  tensor prodict basis of powers.  The simple formula was new to me. To complete the proof ...

I think you can use your approach to complete the proof by using the fact that the Hilbert matrix $(n+m-1)^{-1}$ is positive definite. Then the quadratic form is positive on polynomials and by the Weierstrass theorem on continuous function.
